# PHP imagegrabwindow GD Library returns only black images

Tags: php, gd

I am hoping that there is someone that can help me and many others with this problem...

I want to create a screenshot of a website using the imagegrabwindow function part of php and the GD library

After spending the whole day implementing the code I finally can capture the image and save it to a file, but the image is black and not the image that I expected...

On further investigation I have learned that one of the reasons why the image is black is because apache is not turned on to interact with the desktop - and because of this creates a black image - The issue is I am not running Apache as a server I am running IIS 6...

Is there a setting in Services that I should allow to interact with the desktop? and if there is can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
    $browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
    $handle = $browser->HWND;
    $browser->Visible = true;
    $browser->Fullscreen = true;
    $browser->Navigate("http://localhost/site/advertise/index.asp");

    /* Still working? */
    while ($browser->Busy) {
        com_message_pump(4000);
    }
    $im = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0);
    imagepng($im, "iesnap6.jpg");
    $browser->Quit();
    ?>
```

Thanks to the answers below I have changed imagepng to imagejpeg - But still get a black image...

```
imagejpeg($im, "iesnap7.jpg");
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

I have ammended the code to this: Social Addict still no success with the image showing up in Black!

```
  <?php
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
$handle = $browser->HWND;
$browser->Visible = true;
$browser->Navigate("http://localhost/advertise/index.asp");

/* Still working? */
while ($browser->Busy) {
    com_message_pump(4000);
}
$im = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0);
$browser->Quit();
imagejpeg($im," file2.jpg");
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Social Addict - I have added the header - I am also constantly changing the file1.jpg name to make sure it is not using a black cached images... still no luck!

Comment: are you wanting a png or jpg?

Comment: try setting the header info as i have shown on my post now and access your php file directly throught the browser and see what happens

Comment: no sure if it makes a difference but place the header line just before the image is output ie imagejpeg()

Comment: maybe with vista you need to set exec rights for the InternetExplorer DCOM object via "dcomcnfg"

Comment: http://figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=24 < done this still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before and is often caused when you try and load or convert an image to an incorrect type

I think it may be something to do with this line

```
imagepng($im, "iesnap6.jpg");
```

You are saving it as a png and naming it as a jpg here.

Try the following as you have stated you want [jpeg](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

```
imagejpeg($im, "iesnap6.jpg");
```

instead

Try setting the header type before the imagejpeg call:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

then accessing the script from the browser directly and see if that works?

Also this is another known issue from [PHP.NET](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php)

> This function was painfully slow when
>   I was testing it on my machine. It
>   took about 2 or 3 seconds for it to
>   return an image. It also fails to work
>   if the Apache service doesn't have
>   access to "Interact with the desktop"

Comment: I have changed it to imagepng($im, "iesnap6.pmh"); as well and get the same black image - I do not have Appache installed only running "IIS" as my webserver - which make me thing that I should somehow allow IIS to "Interact with the desktop"

Comment: I mean imagepng($im, "iesnap6.png"); (Spelling Correction)

Comment: go to your iis settings and allow interact with desktop. But the line you just wrote doesnt match to what i suggested... imagejpeg($im," file.jpg");

Comment: Thanks SocialAddict - changed it to imagejpeg($im," file.jpg"); (Still a black image) in settings I cannot find IIS as a service and are assuming it is World Wide Web Publishing Service and allowed "interact with desktop" restarted and made sure the service is running - but still getting a black image...

Comment: You need to call the browser commit command before the imagejpeg() call -or the example on php.net seems to: http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php

Comment: try setting the header type as ive amended above

Answer (score 0):

Are the IIS and WWW Publishingservice allowed to interact with the desktop?

My computer -> manage -> services -> [IIS and WWWPub...] -> LoginTab -> Allow to interact with desktop

Comment: I am running Vista - ->Services->World Wide Web Publishing Service-> LoginTab -> Allow to interact with desktop Assuming that it is the same as [IIS and WWWPub...] do not have the [IIS and WWWPub...] restarted my machine and checked if the service restarted... still getting the Black image

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, try change color resolution to 32 bits and try again.

Comment: Thanks for comming back to me Jass - One of the problems is that my server only handles 16 bit

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with imagegrabwindow(). Eventually, after finding no help with the problem, I decided to see if I could script an existing page-capture plugin or extention. I found that Pearl Crescent Page Saver for Firefox is scriptable from the commandline.

http://pearlcrescent.com/products/pagesaver/doc/#commandline

The Basic version gives you less flexibility than their paid version, but the basic version met my needs. It may also work on non-Windows systems, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue a while back: The main problem were that my dedicated server did not have a 32 bit Graphics Card Installed. This caused the images to display black...

I updated my server hardware and installed a 32 bit graphics card and now it is working with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer that probably will help most. Taken from a commentor on PHP.net:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php

1. Right click '[My] Computer' on your desktop, select 'Manage'
2. Under the 'Services and Applications', double click Services
3. Find your Apache service (possibly IIS) and right click, select Properties
4. From the 'Log on' tab, make sure that 'Allow service to interact with desktop' is enabled
5. Click 'Okay', close out, and then restart Apache (or IIS)

If you don't have this, then Apache can't communicate with your computer desktop and returns a blank image.

Answer (score 0):

The 't' in 'Content-Type' needs to be capital.

Before:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

After:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

It works for me now..